# Floating over div with css

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have this simple website

```
<div style=" position: relative; margin-right: 40px;">
    <div style="float: left; width: 200px; position: relative;">Left Stuff</div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 100px; position: relative;">Middle Stuff</div>
    <div style="float: right; width: 200px; position: relative; margin-right: 40px;">Right Stuff</div>
    <br style="clear: left;" />
</div>
```

and I want that the "right stuff" float over the "middle stuff" and not under the middle stuff on resize the window.

Currend on resize:

```
Left Stuff              Middle Stuff
                               Right Stuff
```

I want:

```
Left Stuff              Middle SRight Stuff
```

How can I get this "effect"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the right div to

`<div style="position:absolute; right:0; width: 200px; margin-right: 40px;">Right Stuff</div>`

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/jmv2e/1/)